# Unable to Check File Out due to File not Being Checked Out

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, check-out

I have the following code, which I use to check out a file from my Document Library:

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/mysite");
var web = ctx.Web;
var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("mysite/documentlibrary/filename.pdf");
file.CheckOut();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code appears to work on most occasions, but sometimes when calling it I get this error message on the last line:

> "The file 'http://sharepoint/mysite/documentlibrary/filename.pdf' is not checked out."

When I navigate to the file in a browser, I can see that the file is indeed not checked out, but the error is not helpful at all as that is what I am trying to do!

**I am also unable to check the file out manually from the browser with the same message.**

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I went into the file properties and selected `Unpublish this version` :

[image]

After doing this and then making sure the file was checked in, I was able to check it out manually as well as with the following code:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(_sitename))
{
    var web = ctx.Web;
    var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
    ctx.Load(file);
    file.CheckOut();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var ctx = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/mysite");
var web = ctx.Web;
var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("mysite/documentlibrary/filename.pdf");
ctx.Load(file);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
file.CheckOut();
```

Comment: This doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't check the file out. I tried adding an `ExecuteQuery` after the last line, but this gave the same error as my original code

Comment: I also just tried checking the file out manually (through the browser) and got the same error - maybe best to start again with a new file...

Comment: that was my next guess, the library had publishing